# How to analyze OWASP ZAP scan results effectively

Tags: owasp, zap

How to analyze OWASP ZAP scan results effectively

After a run, I am getting a lot of URL's which are not vulnerabilities. Is there anyway that we can analyze the reports easily.

Answer (score 1):

The ZAP HTML report should only contain potential issues. If its including things that you think are not issues then you'll need to let us know what they are. Note that

Comment: Are there any official articles that can help to understand the working of ZAP session and when to consider the reported URL as a vulnerability.
Example: 
An URL is reported as a vulnerability by ZAP in the URL and when I tried to open the URL again I am not getting any kind of response which is confusing me.

Comment: Look at all of the information in the alert. If you still dont understand why its been raised then ask on the ZAP user group https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users giving all of the info that you can share.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a strategy:

1. Run the scan
2. Take the highest severity finding
3. Read about it and check with development/other team members is is an issue or not
4. Continue with the next finding on the list
5. Repeat steps 2-4

After that, you will be able to eliminate or address most of the findings, so in the next iteration, you can exclude the non-issues from the scan.